# How to setup my server side script on web server

Tags: php, mysql, server-side, lamp

I have a server-side script which an app connects to. This works perfectly well on my LAMP server running on my development computer but when I uploaded the script to a live web server, I get errors, the latest being Error 404 which is "Not Found". I know it has to do with not putting the files in the right places or perhaps some security setting is responsible. Can people with experience guide me on how to set up my scripts so I can access them?

Here is the structure on my server, and it works: In `/var/www`, I have a folder called `MyAPI` and inside this folder, I have my `index.php` file and 2 supporting files which work together. I also have a folder called `Store` inside the same `MyAPI` folder where I store uploaded documents. I also have a MySQL database which I am connecting to and can read and write from. How do I place these on the server so it is accessible? The error I am getting again is Error 404, how can I be sure the files are found? I disabled `.htaccess` temporarily but it still did not work. Please advise.

CLARIFICATION: Note that my explanation about /var/www is what ALREADY works right now. I was just giving an explanation of the setup on my development computer. The problem is how to transfer the structure unto a LIVE server. Kindly look at the setup described and how this should be transferred to a live server.

**Post Issue: Why does my question have a down-vote?**

Comment: Are you sure your server is serving from `/var/www`? You can check your `httpd.conf` for the correct `DocumentRoot`. Otherwise, are there any other files on the server that you can access? Try searching for them.

Comment: What server are you using (Ubuntu, Windows, Centos etc)?  Which web server?

Comment: @minitech, note that my explanation about /var/www is what ALREADY works right now. I was just giving an explanation of the setup on my development computer. The problem is how to transfer the structure unto a LIVE server. Kindly look at the setup described and how this should be transferred to a live server.

Comment: @shapeshifter, it's a Linux server. Also, read my clarification in my earlier comment.

Comment: @Paulo: Oh, I assumed you put them into `/var/www` on your server too. If not... where *did* you put them?

Comment: @Paulo, yeah you didn't explain much.  From what I understand you have a folder with an index.php, 2 files + a directory.  Copy them into /var/www access with http://server.com/MyAPI/index.php.  Also tail your /var/log/httpd/error_log file while hitting the server and you might see some errors.  Though 404 would suggest you don't so you could check access_log to make sure your request is actually getting to the server.

Comment: @shapeshifter, So you know, the server has the following folder structure when looking at the file manager: Home, (Under it, I have etc, mail, public_ftp, public_html, tmp, www). I copied my folder containing these files (MyAPI) into public_html which automatically copied them into the www folder. I checked access_log and I am sure the requests are getting to the server. Could there be a need to set some permission on the server? Note that this is a hosted server and I there's no option to access the files and folder from the command line.

Comment: @minitech, please find the description on how I put the files in my earlier comment so I don't duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Please make Sure '**Localhost**' is not Hard coded in any of your path... if it is Hard coded you scripts will work Locally but  will show 404  when hosted.

Comment: Given that the OP said he disabled `.htaccess` files, there could be 500 errors or warnings, maybe, but not a 404.

Comment: My server provider gives my server "localhost" and this is what you see when you log into phpMyAdmin (main interface) where it shows the databases, home, logout, etc icons.